# Foundation 6 properly align div (callout) to right on large screen

Tags: sass, zurb-foundation-6

How do I properly align my `<div class="small-6 columns">` (callout) to the right (on large screen) inside the `<div class="row">` in Foundation 6? I am using Sass.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="small-6 columns">
        <div class="callout large">
        <p>This is my callout</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a class `large-offset-6` to `small-6 columns`, it will move six columns to right.

For more information see http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/grid.html